# Sitecore 6.6, MVC 3 and System.Web.Optimization?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, bundle, minify

Sitecore does not support MVC 4 yet and I'd like to use System.Web.Optimization's bundling and minification.

Requests to bundles respond with 404 Not Found.

**BundleConfig.cs** :

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/site.css",
                    "~/Content/960.gs/960.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
    }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml** :

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container_12">
            <a href="/"><h1>Title</h1></a>
            @Html.Action("Utilities", "Navigation")
            @Html.Action("Menu", "Navigation")
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Paths to bundles are virtual and do not map to physical folders.

Ignoring routes throws a NotImplementedException and 500 Internal Server Error:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("content/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("bundles/{*pathInfo}");
```

.. but otherwise, requests are handled by Sitecore and respond with a 404 Not Found + Redirect.

I've also tried:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
        <remove name="BundleModule"/>
        <add type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" name="BundleModule"/>
    </modules>
```

I can't get this all to work together. Help!

Comment: I fear that Sitecore might define a catch all route before the bundles get handled...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mother of GOD!

Hackaround the following routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "sc_ignore_Bundles_Css",
    "content/{*pathInfo}"
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "sc_ignore_Bundles_Js",
    "bundles/{*pathInfo}"
);
```

Comment: Did you have to do anything else to get this to work properly?

I've tried adding the routes, but sitecore keeps hijacking the bundle or content requests and returning an item not found error.

Comment: I don't have this project in my hands anymore but as far as I can remember.. you need to make sure (in some .config file) that the 'exclusion pattern' is set to 'sc_ignore_'.

Comment: I've added /content/ and /bundle/ to the ignoreurlprefixes in the web.config. But it sounds like you're saying I need to add even more to it? I'll google for sc_ignore and see what I can find. Thanks!

As a side note. When I add the urls to the ignoreurlprefix, the staticfile handler kicks in and i just get a regular 404 error =\

Comment: I'm saying that somewhere in a config file is a setting (key/value) that should look like 'sc_ignore_'.. When I saw that, I assumed I could use it to bypasse the Sitecore pipeline. I would try searching (the solution) for 'sc_ignore'.

Comment: Yeah I see that and I tried setting it. It's the same prefix that you used. Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to make a difference. Sitecore is still trying to find an item "content/css" and does the redirect.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Sitecore setting named "IgnoreUrlPrefixes", using a sitecore config include you can patch this setting to include for example "/bundles" which allows you to use the /bundles/* urls for the ASP.NET Web Optimization bundling features.

Comment: Using Sitecore 7.x this seems to be the only thing required `|/bundles`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using Sitecore 6.6 update 5, I was able to get bundling to work by doing the following:

First, add this to the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="BundleModule"/>
    <add type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" name="BundleModule"/>
</modules>
...
```

Second, I added a pipeline method to the  pipeline to register the bundles in the bundle table:

```
[UsedImplicitly]
public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
{
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;            
    RegisterBundles( BundleTable.Bundles );
}

private void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
}
```

Next, I added the pipeline method to the pipeline via a patch file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
   <sitecore>
      <pipelines>
         <initialize>
            <processor patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeGlobalFilters, Sitecore.Mvc']"
               type="MyStuff.Web.Pipelines.RegisterMyBundles, MyStuff.Web" />
         </initialize>
      </pipelines>
   </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Finally, I patched the IgnoreUrlPrefixes setting in sitecore to add the /bundles path

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
   <sitecore>
      <settings>
         <setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes"
                  value="(all other sitecore paths here)|/bundles"/>
      </settings>
   </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

... Nothing else was needed - worked like a champ.